# How do I switch between routers when connected via Ethernet?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vpn, home-networking, routing

I currently have a Windows 7 machine and a Ubuntu 11.10 media server connected via Ethernet to a router. This router (Router 1) is connected to a Singapore ISP which prevents me from accessing IP-based services like Hulu, Netflix etc.

I am thinking of adding a 2nd Router (Router 2) which would connect to a VPN service so that it has a US WAN IP. For Wifi clients, it would then just require connecting to a 2nd Wifi network provided by Router 2 to overcome the IP blocking.

The two PC's connected via ethernet to Router 1 have me stumped though. Is there a command-line way in Windows to change the gateway from Router 1 to Router 2, assuming the Windows PC IP doesn't need to change if Router 1 and Router 2 are on the same sub-net? For the Ubuntu machine, it gets more complex as I don't want to route all traffic to Router 2 - I'm aiming to filter traffic from one application only (Plex) to Router 2, but leave HTTP traffic going to Router 1.

```
+-----------+ 
|           | 
|Windows PC |-------------------+ 
|           |                   | 
|           |                   | 
+-----------+                   | 
                          +-----------+             +-----------+             +-----------+ 
                          |Router 1   |             |           |             |           | 
                          |(Singapore |------+------|Fibre      |-------------|Internet   | 
                          |IP)        |      |      |Terminal   |             |           | 
                          |           |      |      |           |             |           | 
                          +-----------+      |      +-----------+             +-----------+ 
+-----------+                   |            | 
|Ubuntu     |                   |            | 
|Media      |-------------------+            | 
|Server     |                                | 
|           |                                | 
+-----------+                                | 
                          +-----------+      | 
                          |           |      | 
                          |Router 2   |------+ 
                          |(US IP)    | 
                          |           | 
                          +-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a server behind Router 2 (ie ubuntu) and then create a SSH tunnel through the Router 2 directly from your computer behind Router 1. This would essentially cause the computer behind Router 2 to act as a proxy for the computer behind Router 1.

See the link below for steps on how to configure Putty on the computer behind Router 1 to connect via ssh to the computer behind Router 2.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/use-putty-as-a-secure-proxy-on-windows/421

The only software you'd really need on the computer behind Router 2 is openssh-server, shorewall, and fail2ban. If you're worried about having ports open on the firewall then use a zero config VPN like Hamachi from LogMeIn.

Keep in mind that since your traffic will be routed through Router 2, you are going to have to reverse your thinking of uploading/downloading. Let's say you have a 10Mbps/1Mbps (download/upload) on Router 1 and the same speeds on Router 2.

Your Computer behind Router 1 can download at 10Mbps. However, the server behind Router 2 can only upload at 1Mbps. This means that your server behind Router 2 will download the Hulu content at 10Mbps and upload it to the Computer behind Router 1 at 1Mbps. When you send requests or upload something from Computer behind Router 1, it can only upload at 1Mbps which means that your server behind Router 2 can only download from Computer behind Router 1 at 1Mbps.

To sum up, your computer, when using the SSH Proxy will only have a max speed of 1Mbps/1Mbps given this scenario. You will want to invest in fast upload speeds of your Router 2's ISP to at least try and match the download speeds of your Router 1.

Comment: I'm reasonably familiar with SSH tunnels but I'm not clear on how the Ubuntu machine is connecting to Router 2? Are you suggesting I unplug the Ubuntu machine from Router 1 and have it connected only to Router 2? Regarding your comment on upload/download speeds, I assume you referring to the speed of the VPN ISP? Both Router1 and Router2 are connected to the same local ISP so local speeds are the same.

Comment: @kobaltz: I think you're missing that the two routers are sitting right next to each other.